# How can I install a NC375i network card on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: server, networking, drivers, hardware, hp

How can I install a NC375i network card on Ubuntu 12.04?

The server I am using is an HP Proliant ML370 G6.

The HP help doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Network-Card BIOS (ethtool -i eth0).
It must be 4.0.585.
If not please use the HP update site to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lander's anwer I look for a way to upgrade the firmeware of the card, I didn't found anything for ubuntu on HP site ...

I didn't want to install RHE6 I fetched CentOS6 liveCD and then install the rpm from hp website
http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_527f3e47b68d42479df5aa4b1a#tab4